# Google Sign-In for iOS and OAuth

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, gcloud, google-cloud-billing

I have enabled Sign In with Google in my iOS app and I am confused about the pricing.

While making my OAuth certificates on the console I had to upgrade my account to a billing account (my account was previously connected to a free firebase account that did not have billing). I made a new project for the OAuth certificates.

I assumed that utilising sign in with google would be free, but I’m less sure because I had to make a billing account and enter a credit card now.

There are many “identity” products advertised on the Google cloud webpage, and I’m certain I’m not using any of them (I’m simply using the GoogleSignInSwift package on iOS and entering the OAuth credentials in my Supabase backend).

When I look under billing, there is an account, but none of my projects are linked to it.

Questions:

- why do I have to make a billing account with a credit card if I’m not using a paid service?
- is using sign in with google like I am free or is it really one of these identity products.

I’m quite certain it’s free but I wanted to please check. Navigating the offerings and the console takes a lot of getting used to.

EDIT:

I am calling `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn` from GoogleSignInSwift package, and then passing the accessToken and idToken and creating a `OpenIDConnectCredentials` which I send to my backend (Supabase in this instance) to create/signin/authenticate a user.

Comment: Edit your question to show exactly what your app is doing. Google **Sign In** is free. Google Identity Platform is free for up to 49 users or 49,999 users depending on features [link](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing). Firebase also has authentication with the same pricing as Identity Platform [link](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). To get the best answer, details matter.

Comment: Note: adding a credit card does not mean you will be charged. A credit card helps verify your identity. Create a billing alert with a small amount such as $5.00. If the alert is triggered (emailed), review in detail your billing account to know for sure what you are being charged for [link](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated my question with some specific calls I am making. I am unsure if I am using the Google Identity Platform in the way I am using OpenIDConnectCredentials with Supabase to authenticate my user in my backend. My confusion comes from the fact I am not storing any users or identity info in GCP.